# Do Until loop fault

Tags: powershell

```
do{
$ActionVariable = Read-host "Do you want to delete a folder or empty a folder ? [D/E]"
}
until($ActionVariable = "E" -or"D") 

Read-host
```

Hello, I am trying to write a script that lets a user choose to empty a folder or delete it as a whole. I wrote a do until loop that does not seem to function. Am I defining the until wrong ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work better:
`until ($ActionVariable -eq 'E' -or $ActionVariable -eq 'D')`

Or perhaps this:
`until ('E','D' -contains $ActionVariable)`

Comment: That works indeed. However, why wouldn't 

until ($ActionVariable -contains 'E','D') work? Because that seems to loop endlessly.

Comment: The order is indeed important: your version would check if the entered _string_ contains the specified string _array_ (which is always false, hence the endless loop), whereas the other way around it checks if the specified string _array_ contains the entered _string_.

Comment: @SiemHermans PowerShell v3 added the `-in` operator which is used in the reverse order: `until($ActionVariable -in 'E', 'D')`

Comment: @Rynant: Great, I knew something like that was available but could not put my finger on it; thanks!